# ParseUI PFLogInViewController - Specifying fields

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, parseui

I'm building an app using Parse and I'm trying to make use of PFLogInViewController, but I cannot at all find out how to get custom fields (such as the Facebook & Twitter buttons) to show.

I'm using Swift and I've tried every suggestion I could find.

Below is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI


class LoginViewController: PFLogInViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var logInController = PFLogInViewController()

        logInController.fields = PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword
            | PFLogInFields.LogInButton
            | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton
            | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten;

        logInController.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(logInController, animated:true, completion: nil)
    }        
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I should mention, the login form displays, but only with the default fields.

Comment: Have you subclassed it?

Comment: @GaryHarrower Did you find a solution to this? I have been working on this exact same problem for more time than I'd like to admit.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `PFLogInFields.Facebook` and `PFLogInFields.Twitter` to your `LogInViewController` fields.